# Create one tag according to given info on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this form on my website:

```
<form action>
    <input type = "number" placeholder = "Combat ID" name = "combat id" min = "0" max = "9999999999" required/>
    <button type = "button" id = "check_button">Check</button>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "Character" style = "color:white;">Character</label>
        <select id = "Character" name = "Character">
            List of chars
        </select>
    </div>
    <h2 style = "color:white;padding-top:2%;">Other info</h2>
    ...............
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

What I want is when you enter combat id you click the button "Check" then in select box it shows only these 5 characters that were in that combat.I get these 5 character names from API,when submitting combat id to API.

So when a user clicks the button "Check" I need to send request to API with given combat id and then accordingly fill the select tag.

Comment: This question is a little to broad in its current format. There are multiple steps required here, and you show not attempt at any of them. You need to get the `combat id` value (note, you should not have spaces in your input names as this will cause you headaches later on). You need to use ajax to post that `combat id` value to you API. You need to get the returned data from the API and covert it to `option` elements. There are many examples of all these steps here on SO. You need to show some effort, and explain what you need help with. No one should be writing full/free code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not gonna spoon feed you and tell you everything, but I will give you a good head start.

Since you've allowed jQuery, here is how I'd do it:

jQuery code:

`<input id="combat-id" type = "number" placeholder = "Combat ID" name = "combat id" min = "0" max = "9999999999" required/>`

Basically, I gave the Combat ID field an id of `combat-id`

Now, on this JS code, what you do is, you call the $() function in the jQuery library, and pass it a selector `#check_button` and you add an event listener to it. You call the on function on the selector, and give it the action in string for the first argument, and in the second argument, you pass a closure to be executed when this event happens.
On the first line, you get the value in the `#combat-id` field.

```
$('#check_button').on('click', function (event) {

    var combatId = $('#combat-id').val();

    // Do what you want with it now.

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The `event.preventDefault();` is called to stop the page from refreshing. The closure in the second argument is passed an event variable which can be used to do various things in the event.

So now, you only have to call the API now and populate the list. You can do it very easily.

If you wanna do a POST request, do this:

`$.post('/url/to/go', { var: val, combatId: combatId });`

Or for a GET request:

`$.get('/url/to/go', { var: val, combatId: combatId });`

Since you are using PHP, you can get the `combatId` like this:

`$_GET['combatId']` or `$_POST['combatId']` depending on the REQUEST method you chose.

You can assign each request to a variable like this:

`var request = $.post(....);`

And do something like:

```
request.success( function (data) {
   // the data variable will have data you displayed to the screen.
});

request.error( function (error) {
  // this will be called if the request failed. The error variable will have some sort of error info.
});
```

So in this code, you can put some code in the `.success()` function to populate the list. What you can do is output content using PHP in the JSON format, and you can parse it in JavaScript like this:

`data = JSON.parse(data)`

What this will do is, it will convert the JSON (JavaScript Object Notation, a language to represent JS like objects, which is a String in JavaScript) to native a JavaScript Object.

To append, give the `<select>` tag an id, lets say `#select`

Then, you can select it and add strings to it like this:

`$('#select').append('<option value="' + data.value + '">' + data.text + '</option>');`

In here, I assume data is an object with two properties: `value` and `text` and I append that data into the `<select>` list.

Comment: You mix-matched a quote and a backtick in `$('#combat-id\`)`.

Comment: @Sean Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Added more details and explanation.

Comment: I want to get that list of characters before submitting form.Doesn't your PHP part require to submit form first?
I have been getting data from that API using php,because Javascript doesnt allow json calls to external websites.So I am thinking,when you listen to event when a button is clicked in javascript and when it's clicked you call php function to get that information?

Comment: @ESipalis I use something called AJAX. Using the `$.post` and `$.get` you can send a request in JavaScript. To stop submitting the form, there is `event.preventDefault();` Think of it just like a click event utility, that doesn't refresh the page and reset the form.

Comment: @ESipalis Once the button is clicked, like the code I gave you, in the `.success()` area, you will get the data, parse it and then update the form. That is it. It won't submit the form. You can have a separate button for it.

Comment: @ESipalis I added more content and explanation. Refresh it, and re-read it to understand the concept better.

Comment: Ok,I managed to do it,but like I said,I get error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked. Javascript policy doesn't allow to do requests from external websites.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Also I didn't add that PHP part anywhere,as I am not where to put that PHP code.

Comment: Also if you are using another API that isnnot yours, dont worry about PHP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99451/discussion-between-hassan-althaf-and-esipalis).

Comment: @ESipalis Have any plans to tick this answer as right?

Comment: I am sorry,I was a bit gone cause of New Years and stuff.You really helped me a lot.Thank you and Happy New Year!

Comment: @ESipalis Welcome, and Happy new year too!